# OpenAPI specification - common headers

Tags: openapi, rate-limiting, response-headers

we are implementing an API Management capability and we are applying some transformations to the OAS provided based on the enabled features (Auth, etc).

One of the features that I see always present is rate limiting, and I am aware of `X-RateLimit-*` headers being applied by our product.

Is it a best practice to add those headers in the OAS for customers to be aware of them?

Is there a way to define in OAS 3.0.3 or 3.1.0 common headers to apply in multiple responses?

Comment: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1586 might be a good read, especially the comments below.